# Gallery OnActivityResult is not working in TabActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-gallery, android-tabactivity

i got problem with my code , i am trying to get image from the gallery and show it on my xml layout **(The problem is when i click on the button it goes to the gallery but when i select a picture it just gees to another tab )**

1) my main class which creates the tabs

```
public class MainUser extends TabActivit 
  .....

TabSpec tabSpec10 = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1");
        tabSpec10.setIndicator("Report incident ");
        Context ctx10 = this.getApplicationContext();
        Intent i10 = new Intent(ctx10, ucrimereport.class);
        tabSpec10.setContent(i10);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec10);
```

2) this is the class where i am making and calling the gallery

```
public class ucrimereport extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnItemSelectedListener {
    private static final int IMAGE = 1;

@Override   

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ureport);
.........
         gallary = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sdpic_button);

gallary.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // gallary
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, IMAGE);

        }
    });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==IMAGE){
       Uri selectedImage=data.getData();
       String path=getPath(selectedImage);

       Bitmap bitmapImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
       //ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
       image.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

      }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri){
      String[] filePathColumn={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

      Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

      return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try that code .

```
public class ImageGalleryDemoActivity extends Activity {    
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that works like dream , can you please tell me how to get image from camera i.e. when i open the camera how do i get the image ?

Comment: Try This Link:   http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2011/08/get-camera-capture-image-path-in.html